# Open Folder Using Window Powershell With Space In Path Using .bat File

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to open the user folder using the bat file but getting an error.

my user path is: **C:\Users\Shivjeet Singh**

Bat File Content: **start %USERPROFILE%**

And getting this error
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpWbn.jpg)

This Error Is **Due To Space In Path**.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the content of your question, why are you are using powershell.exe to run py.exe and/or python.exe which in turn invokes a Windows batch file, to launch explorer.exe via cmd.exe's built in `start` command.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Explorer` instead using the command `Start` to open the folder user !

```
@echo off
Explorer "%userprofile%"
```